# Concat(first name, " ", lastname) like OR email like causing duplicate output

Tags: php, sql

I have an SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user, user_company, company
WHERE user.user_id = user_company.user_id AND
      user_company.company_id = '$company_id' AND
      user_company.company_id = company.company_id AND 
      CONCAT(user.user_first_name, ' ', user.user_last_name) LIKE '%$l%' OR user.user_email LIKE '%$l%'
LIMIT 5
```

This seems to work on returning the values whether the user inputs something that's similar to the name or the email, however a flaw in this is if the user inputs the email, the record will be duplicated.

user_company doesn't contain any email data; it's only contained in the user table.

How do I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Your problem is lack of parentheses.  Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u JOIN
     user_company uc
     ON (user_id) JOIN
     company c
     ON (company_id)
WHERE uc.company_id = '$company_id' AND
      (CONCAT(u.user_first_name, ' ', u.user_last_name) LIKE '%$l%' OR
       u.user_email LIKE '%$l%'
      )
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This isn't returning anything anymore. It's returning NULL.

Comment: So does the above join the company_id with user and user_company? Because user doesn't contain any company_id, that's only present in company and user_company.

Comment: @Majo0od . . . The `USING` clause matches the named column (or columns) in any tables that have the columns.